# Parse JSON Colum of Spark Dataframe with Variable Schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase

I have a Dataframe column in JSON format with variable schema. I have to parse the data in column and put it in Hbase. For Eg. as in below is column of dataframe with JSON  :

```
Col1
{“Name”:”Ram”,”Place”:”RamGarh”}
{“Name”:”Lakshman”,”Place”:”LakshManPur”.”DepartMent”:”Operations”}
{“Name”:”Sita”,”Place”:”SitaPur”,”Experience”,”14”}
```

I need to parse this JSON data. What should be most efficient way? So that at least I can present in form of key -> value form.

```
Ram->       (Place -> Ramgarh)
Lakshman -> (Place -> LakshmanPur,
             Department -> Operations)
```

I have to insert data in Hbase with Name and key and others as columns.

Comment: what you have tried and failed so far

Comment: I am trying since last 18 hours  . . tried various approach . . none succeeded... trying to get row as map  but since its of Column is string type so not working.. . .tried parsing using JSON but somehow it also dont work......Challenge still lies how to parse JSON of variable schema stores as string in DF column.

Comment: can you paste the code of  how you printed dataframe.show ?

Comment: I cant  as I am working on VDI and cant login Stackoverflow over there.  Basically I have a DF [col1:String]   and this string contains JSON of variable schema